# GIMP - edit mask layer to adjust visible region

Tags: gimp, background-removal

What I want to do as following:

1. use remove.bg tool to remove image (bg.jpg) background, I got a png file (bg_remove.png) with background removed (not perfect).
2. use gimp to scale bg_remove.png to the same size as bg.jpg.
3. load bg.jpg to gimp and apply mask from bg_remove.png.
4. try to edit the mask layer to ajust the not perfect region.

The first 3 steps is good but when I do it in step 4, I can select a region, then file black color to make the region visible, but for some other part i want to hide, when I try to select the region then fill the white color, it does't take effect.

Is it correct to fill white color to erase something?
[image]

Comment: I don't recommend that online tool. GIMP 2.10 has its own Foreground Select functionality which can make better masks. There's a good tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhRGix-x5Mg

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks, since that tool say it use AI, then I guess it's more better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the layer mask is really an opacity, higher values are more opaque, so you fill with black what should be transparent and with white what should be opaque.

Given the output of your external tool, using Gimp built-in [Foreground selector](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-foreground-select.html) or the "Extract foreground" function in the GMIC filter suite would have been faster.

Comment: Have to agree, GIMP's built-in Foreground Select function (with the "Matting Levin" engine selected) is not only quicker, but also more refinable, and also makes a far better job of masking.

Comment: @BillyKerr I am using 2.10.10 on macosx, but sounds like no option to select "Matting Levin".

Comment: @beetlej Your Tool option dialog should look [like this](https://imgur.com/YTsJJgH)

Comment: @BillyKerr Hmmm, my gimp only should "Matting Global" and not selectable (gray out). Is it a external need to be install?

Comment: @beetlej Absent from some builds. Where did you get your version? See https://www.reddit.com/r/GIMP/comments/8vtpmz/foreground_select_tool_levinmatting/  but the other one could already be better than what you showed us.

Comment: @xenoid yes - even the Global engine makes a good job, although you have to paint the whole foreground subject in solid I've found, which is a bit of a pain.

Comment: @xenoid I download it for official site. Today I try the same version on windows, The Matting Levin" tool is there, but macosx version no such option.